# Django sitemap.xml - where is it?

Tags: python, xml, django, nginx, django-sitemaps

I've made a sitemap for my website using `Django-sitemaps`, the compilation went ok, the file is created, but I don't know from where can I access to it.

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from sitemap import ContratalosSitemap

#Declaration for sitemaps url

sitemaps = {
    'pages' : ContratalosSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'apps.contratalos.views',
    url(r'c/(?P<slug>\.*[^ ]{1,128})?/', 'c', name='content'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
)
```

The file is created on shared folder, where my templates are, as far as I know, this should be accessed from root url, ie: www.contratalos.com/sitemap.xml

But it says Not found, I don't know if this is a nginx configuration or maybe I am missing something on this...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is my sitemap.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from datetime import datetime

class ContratalosSitemap(Sitemap):

def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

def items(self):
    return self.names

def changefreq(self, obj):
    return 'weekly'

def lastmod(self, obj):
    return datetime.now()

def location(self, obj):
    return reverse(obj)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I opened a new one regarding this issue, thanks.

Comment: @NeoVe don't "vote to close", just delete it.

Comment: I can't because it has an answer

Comment: the link to dupe question is dead "This question is an exact duplicate of:
Django sitemap.xml - Error 500"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
http://yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
```

It is dynamically generated - it is not a file.

Comment: Yes, http://contratalos.com/sitemap.xml , but it is not found, what may be causing this?